# RIA Services partial class issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

In RIA Services I define some partial class for the entity. (It is under *.shared.cs)

This partial class has some new fields that doesn't have entity.

And I have a **method to populate those fields of the entity including the extra partial class fields.**

When I debug that RIA Services method I can see that ALL Partial class fields are populated well. So they are NOT NULL.

When I get callback from RIA Services in Silverlight code (MVVM)  I can see ALL fields:

1. Basic entities fields.
2. Extra partial class fields.

**!!! But the partial class fields are NULL !!!**

What I am missing there? Any clue?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found other way to realize things I need:

I just created a SQL Server View and that's it! :)

So I recommend to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Please add a [DataMemberAttribute()] attribute (System.Runtime.Serialization namespace) to partial class properties.

Comment: Well... I get an error. It says that that type is already contains a definition...

Comment: Try inherit your partial class from EntityObject

Comment: Attributes and inheritance should be implemented on server side. Your entity is child class of EntityObject by default.

Comment: Those members that you want to share data must not be defined in the `.shared.cs` file. The WCF RIA tools will create the properties in Silverlight for you.